# How to route through another gateway in the tunnel

Tags: networking, router, routing

I use openvpn that routes nicely through all connected gateways to their respective networks. 
So my **main** router has 
**eth0** IP `192.168.1.1` with 
**tun0** device `192.168.94.2`
 Each external router connects to this main router gets IP address in the `192.168.94.0/24` range and I connect two networks via tun0 dev. 
I have general routing statement:
 `192.168.0.0/16 via 192.168.94.2 dev tun0`
 and all works fine, as well as:
 `iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.0.0/16 -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT`
 so no NAT between private IP range. 
But I have another local tunnel at one of my routers **rh** with
 **eth0** IP `192.168.10.1` (network `192.168.10.0/24`)
 **tun0** `192.168.94.69` 
and **tun1** `192.168.95.2` (which has connection and access to network `192.168.11.0/24`)

Is it possible to have access from **main** router to the subnet `192.168.11.0/24` via **rh** router?
I tried adding route:
`ip ro add 192.168.11.0/24 via 192.168.94.69 onlink dev tun0` 
but packets do not route.  I tried adding `via 192.168.10.1` but also no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Gateway routes don't work with `tun` interfaces, as those do not carry a link-layer header.

When routes specify a gateway with `via ...`, this actually gets resolved to a *link-layer* address (i.e. it becomes the "destination MAC" address in the Ethernet header) that directs the packet to the correct host. The packets never specify the gateway by its IP address, only by its MAC.

But as `tun` interfaces don't have link-layer addressing, there is only one possible destination that packets can take, and your route behaves exactly like `192.168.0.0/16 dev tun0` (the "gateway" field is just ignored).

To achieve what you want, you have several options:

1. Use the OpenVPN server's `iroute` option, which tells OpenVPN to internally forward packets to a specific client based on the destination IP address, after the OS routes the packet through tun0.

   See https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/RoutedLans for more details.
2. Switch your VPN to `tap` interface type, which *does* have link-layer addressing – 'tap' interfaces carry full Ethernet frames, not just IP packets. (Note that Android/iOS don't support 'tap' VPNs.)

Comment: Thanks @user1686 for that info.  So I should add extra iroute option in the `rh` router which has this extra tunnel interface.  I can't see how could I route traffice to my `main` router.  But it makes sense, as I have similar situations on the local net `eth0` dev where I for example route 192.168.3.0/24 via 192.168.1.5 and works fine.

Comment: No, if I understood everything correctly, you need it on the _main_ router, to create an internal OpenVPN route of 192.168.11.0/24 via the 'rh' client (as your example had "via 192.168.94.69" and that's basically "via rh").

Comment: Yes @user1686 I want to access 192.168.11.0/24 from `main` router.  So I would need to add iroute for the client **rh** (192.168.10.0/24 to add 192.168.11.0/24 network)?  I'll try to do this, but need some time so I don't reset all routers during the working day

Comment: I tried adding `iroute 192.168.11.0` in the ccd file, but still not accessible .11.0/24 network.  Does it require some extra **routes** on the main router?.

Comment: Yes, it does still need the whole `ip ro add 192.168.11.0/24 dev tun0` part – the iroute only takes effect once packets enter tun0. And the remote network needs to have some routes back to you, too.